# When accessing a Linked List sequentially is it just as efficient as an Array List [Java]

Tags: java, list

If I have two Lists of x length with one being a `LinkedList<Integer>` and one being a `ArrayList<Integer>` when accessing them sequentially which will be faster? I know that linked lists are faster to add/remove elements while array lists are faster for getting/updating elements but is that negated when accessing them sequentially. If the array list is faster is their a quicker way to iterate thought a linked list? I know that technically depending on the use case a stream would be faster.

Code would look something like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>;
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
for (Integer i : list) {
    // Something
}
```

With `List` being either `LinkedList` or `ArrayList`

Comment: In theory both are O(n), but in practice linked lists are probably slightly slower due to how data is stored in memory. But if you need to optimize so far, probably you should be doing C/C++ and not Java.

Comment: What gave you the idea that streams would be faster?

Comment: If you need to manipulate every index of a `List` wouldn't streams be faster?